# how to retrieve result from object(stdClass) in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to retrieve data from an sql query, in codeigniter. but when I am trying to fetch query result ,I am getting only one field. In the query I have trying to get 2 fields. When I try to print the query result using **var_dump** the result I am getting is

`object(stdClass)#33 (1) { ["product_id"]=> string(4) "1904" }`

My Query is:

```
$this->db->select("product_id","product_name")
            ->from('sale_items')
            ->where('sale_items.sale_id',4221);
            $q1 = $this->db->get();
            if ($q1->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach (($q1->result()) as $row1) {
            $data1[] = $row1;
            }
            } else {
            $data1 = NULL;
            }
            echo "<br>";
            foreach($data1 as $prdtname)
            {   echo "<br>";
            echo var_dump($prdtname);
            echo "<br>";
            }
```

and the result is:

```
object(stdClass)#32 (1) { ["product_id"]=> string(4) "1887" } 

object(stdClass)#33 (1) { ["product_id"]=> string(4) "1904" }
```

As you see, I am not getting the second field that is `product_name`. I do not know what is the problem with my query.Can anyone help me.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this code = $prdtname->product_id

Comment: Do you know what will happen to your `foreach($data1 as $prdtname)` when $data is null ?? It will show an error, invalid argument passed to foreach .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your select statement to :

```
 $this->db->select("product_id ,product_name")
```